# Symfony2 Twig: how to use config.yml variables inside template without setting twig globals?

Tags: variables, symfony, global-variables, twig

How could I get value from my config.yml file but not set as Twig global. for example:

```
mopa_boostrap:
    initializr:
        meta: ~
```

when I try

```
{{ mopa_bootstrap.initializr.meta }}
```

i got error that there is no such variable set in this template.

**UPDATE**
As it is not possible to do without Twig Globals, I've done Twig extension which maps selected variables from config.yml to Twig Globals and make them available from template.

for whole implementation look here: https://github.com/nysander/MopaBootstrapBundle/commit/d36269184cfad6d8fd465d8b622f92a302dea104

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution might be creating a twig extension with a function outputting what you want. Twig extension would be registered as a service and you could pass anything you want to it.

Comment: I managed to do Twig extension. thank you both Kuba & Anton for hints.

Comment: Feel free to share it with the community and publish the link to it here. :)

Comment: most part of this implementation is in this commit: https://github.com/nysander/MopaBootstrapBundle/commit/d36269184cfad6d8fd465d8b622f92a302dea104 look also on whole Configuration.php file and base_initializr.html.twig template for usage cases.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. You have to set globals to use them in twig.

Comment: even with some TwigExtension?

Comment: If you write twig extension which will map some parameters from config.yml into globals, then it might work, but as far as I know this is not good idea mainly because config might contain secure data (db passwords, etc) and it should not expose this in templates.

Comment: I meant to make extension which maps only variables I want to twig globals not the whole config.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You can pass service container, for example, into twig extension service and initialize variables you need.